# How to open the file in class in mfc?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

While trying to open the file in Class in function oninitdialog(),It throws exception.If I open the file globally , it works.
How to overcome this?
why the fopen command is behaving like these?

Regards,

karthik

Comment: There is something wrong you might be doing. Post the code.

Comment: please post some code, this would help a lot in answering!

Comment: Can you please be more specific and perhaps write the code with which you're trying to open the file.

AViD

Comment: I updated my question please again read these

Comment: @kartik: no changes in the question. Only the initial question is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I made a mistake by creating file descriptor in OninitDialog function in mfc.To overcome this , I create the file descriptor in constructor of the class.